# Whiteout (missing UI graphics) on toolbar icons in Yosemite

Tags: macos, ui

Getting this weird UI whiteout on all toolbar icons all of a sudden. Any idea how to get rid of this? I have been using this version of OS X for a while with no problems at all.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart into Safe Mode by holding Shift on boot, then log in, then reboot normally. This clears any broken caches.

Also try disabling TotalFinder and other Finder extensions if the problem persists.

Comment: why didn't i think of that? haha thank you VERY much. Its working fine now. It also fixed another issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this

[image]

Instead of this ?

[image]

It's the new default since Yosemite - translucent menu bar [it shows the desktop behind] & also some app windows, Mail, Safari etc

Disable it with System Prefs > Accessibility > Display > Reduce Transparency.

[image]

Comment: I think the OP means, that He does not have icons on His toolbar buttons.

Comment: ah, yeah - you might be right

Comment: no, just trying to get the toolbar icons visible again.